# i am getting "Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'" while lauching on android emulator? android

Tags: android, genymotion

```
09-29 11:52:52.236      396-396/? D/SystemUIService﹕ loading: class com.android.systemui.power.PowerUI
09-29 13:33:42.935      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:34:27.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:34:32.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:34:37.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:34:42.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:34:47.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:34:52.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:34:57.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:02.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:07.943      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:12.939      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:17.943      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:22.943      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:27.943      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:32.943      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:37.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:42.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:47.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:52.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:35:57.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:00.023      321-324/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 695K, 13% free 13963K/15943K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 25ms
09-29 13:36:02.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:07.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:12.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:17.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:22.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:27.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:32.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:37.947      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:42.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:47.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:52.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:36:57.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:02.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:07.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:12.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:17.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:22.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:27.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:32.951      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:37.955      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:39.591        57-57/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:37:39.591        57-57/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:37:39.591      321-395/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:37:39.591      321-395/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:37:39.591      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:37:39.591      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:37:39.591      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:37:42.955      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:47.955      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:52.955      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:37:57.955      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:02.955      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:07.955      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:12.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:17.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:22.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:27.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:32.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:37.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:42.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:47.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:52.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:38:57.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:02.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:07.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:12.959      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:17.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:22.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:27.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:30.335      455-460/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 432K, 5% free 11214K/11783K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 5ms
09-29 13:39:32.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:37.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:42.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:47.963      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:52.967      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:39:57.967      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:02.967      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:07.967      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:12.967      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:17.967      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:22.967      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:27.971      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:32.971      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:37.971      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:42.971      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:47.971      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:52.971      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:40:57.971      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:02.971      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:07.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:12.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:17.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:20.483        57-57/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:41:20.483        57-57/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:41:22.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:27.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:30.623        57-57/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:41:30.623        57-57/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:41:30.623      321-395/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:41:30.623      321-395/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:41:30.623      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:41:30.623      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:41:30.623      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:41:32.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:37.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:42.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:47.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:52.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:41:57.975      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:02.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:07.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:12.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:17.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:22.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:27.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:32.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:37.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:42.979      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:47.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:52.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:42:57.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:02.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:07.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:12.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:17.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:22.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:27.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:32.983      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:37.987      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:42.987      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:47.987      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:52.987      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:43:57.987      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:02.987      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:07.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:12.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:17.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:22.963      321-451/? W/ThrottleService﹕ unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
09-29 13:44:22.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:27.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:32.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:37.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:42.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:47.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:52.991      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:44:57.995      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:02.995      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:07.995      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:12.995      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:17.995      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:22.995      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:27.995      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:32.995      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:37.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:42.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:47.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:52.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:45:57.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:02.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:07.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:12.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:17.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:23.003      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:27.999      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:33.003      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:38.003      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:43.003      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:48.003      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:53.003      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:46:58.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:03.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:08.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:13.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:18.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:23.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:28.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:33.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:38.007      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:43.011      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:48.011      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:53.011      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:58.011      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:47:59.391        57-57/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:47:59.391        57-57/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:47:59.391      321-395/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:47:59.391      321-395/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:47:59.391      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:47:59.391      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:47:59.391      321-334/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:48:03.011      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:08.015      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:10.211      123-303/? W/genymotion_audio﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
09-29 13:48:10.219      472-472/? D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
09-29 13:48:10.231      472-472/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 127K, 23% free 17736K/22855K, paused 0ms+4ms, total 11ms
09-29 13:48:10.235      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 2933, 92416, 2719552
09-29 13:48:11.527      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8b75fc0): name, size, mSize = 3078, 92416, 2811968
09-29 13:48:11.603      472-472/? D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
09-29 13:48:11.611      472-472/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 134K, 22% free 17827K/22855K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 8ms
09-29 13:48:12.695      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8c54c08): name, size, mSize = 3147, 36864, 2848832
09-29 13:48:12.703      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8c11478): name, size, mSize = 3148, 36864, 2885696
09-29 13:48:12.711      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8ce80a0): name, size, mSize = 3149, 36864, 2922560
09-29 13:48:12.727      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8ce8470): name, size, mSize = 3150, 36864, 2959424
09-29 13:48:13.015      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:13.419      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8cd34c8): name, size, mSize = 3191, 4096, 2963520
09-29 13:48:13.431      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8cd9e20): name, size, mSize = 3192, 253000, 3216520
09-29 13:48:13.503      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8cdf758): name, size, mSize = 3194, 59536, 3276056
09-29 13:48:13.507      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8cf6598): name, size, mSize = 3195, 171600, 3447656
09-29 13:48:13.519      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8c49958): name, size, mSize = 3196, 171600, 3619256
09-29 13:48:13.523      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8b26238): name, size, mSize = 3197, 223600, 3842856
09-29 13:48:13.523      472-472/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8ce7698): name, size, mSize = 3198, 238716, 4081572
09-29 13:48:14.115      123-340/? W/AudioWatchdog﹕ Insufficient CPU for load: expected=50.0 actual=139.2 ms; underruns=9 logs=3
09-29 13:48:15.335      321-324/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 721K, 13% free 13962K/15943K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 37ms
09-29 13:48:18.015      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:23.015      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:28.015      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:33.015      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:38.019      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:43.019      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:48.019      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:53.019      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:48:58.019      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:49:03.019      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:49:08.019      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:49:12.311        57-57/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:49:12.311        57-57/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
09-29 13:49:12.311      321-395/? I/ClipboardService﹕ Got clipboard for user=0
09-29 13:50:08.027      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:50:13.027      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
09-29 13:50:18.027      321-348/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
```

When i launched the app on genymotion i got above error messages.
I'm using windows 8.1 operating system and i have installed haxm in sdk.

i continuously getting "Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
to resolve it what i gonna do?
Please try to solve this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: mind putting relevant code

Comment: have got any answer which resolves these issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue a while ago, solved doing this:
You need to change in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

to

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

this worked for me.